# What's the rationale behind value-based classes not being able to inherit from base class with instance fields

Tags: java, inheritance, java-16

The final qualifier specced out at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-16-ga/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html#L55 is:

```
    <li>the class is final, and extends either <code>Object</code> or a hierarchy of
        abstract classes that declare no instance fields or instance initializers
        and whose constructors are empty.</li>
```

This means that a simple case:

```
public abstract class Base {
  protected final int f1;
  protected Base(int f1) { this.f1 = f1; }
}

public final class Child extends Base {
  private final int f2;
  public static Child create(int f1, int f2) { return new Child(f1, f2); }
  private Child(int f1, int f2) { super(f1); this.f2 = f2; }
  // equals, hashCode over f1, f2
}
```

while the "inlined" version would be VBC:

```
public final class Inlined {
  private final int f1;
  private final int f2;
  public static Inlined create(int f1, int f2) { return new Inlined(f1, f2); }
  private Inlined(int f1, int f2) { this.f1 = f1; this.f2 = f2; }
  // equals, hashCode over f1, f2
}
```

What was the rationale for making such a harsh restriction to be a VBC, instead of relaxing it towards "all instance fields (including the ones from parent class) need to participate in equals/hashCode etc." ?

Comment: For one, unknown state can be imposed by introducing a field to a parent class without the VBC knowing about it, which facilitates violating another tenet listed there: *the class's methods treat instances as <em>freely substitutable</em>
        when equal, meaning that interchanging any two instances <code>x</code> and
        <code>y</code> that are equal according to <code>equals()</code> produces no
        visible change in the behavior of the class's methods;*

Comment: Great point! But the same argument applies even to today's contract, doesn't it? - we can have a no-field superclass that is changes to now have a field. It feels like if we wanted to avoid changes then we'd need to inherit from Object directly, as we can't ever stop the base from being changed in an unpredictable fashion. Practice being different: just make it sealed and document the contract.

Comment: TBH Java's `record` type supplants this line of thought.

Comment: This document is [part of the published official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html), so you can link to there rather than github.

Comment: @Bohemian except for “*the class does not declare (or has deprecated any) accessible constructors*” for value types while records force the existence of such a constructor. The closest you can get when you want value type semantics with `record` types, is to have a non-`public` `record` type and provide access to it via an interface having the `record` type’s instance methods and a `static` factory method.